# Identity_Insert with Aspnet.Identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm migrating users to AspNet.Identity schema. I must use int based primary keys. I want to migrate users from the old table to the new `Aspnet.Users` tables so that the old primary key value is also used in the new table for the same record.

For that I have enabled `Identity_Insert` but `UserManager` ignores it. Is it possible to use int based PK-s and have `UserManager` insert predefined values into the Identity column?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        AppContext appctx = new AppContext();
        IdUserStore store = new IdUserStore(appctx);
        IdUserManager manager = new IdUserManager(store);

        DbContextTransaction t = appctx.Database.BeginTransaction();

        appctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET Identity_INSERT  dbo.AspNetUsers ON");

        IdUser u = new IdUser()
        {
            //id is set, UserManagerManager ignores this values in the insert
            Id = 123, 
            UserName = "examplename", 
            Email = "hello@example.com"
        };

        IdentityResult r = manager.CreateAsync(u).Result;

        t.Commit();
    }
```

The exception thrown says:

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'AspNetUsers' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

This is the generated T-SQL, its missing the Id value that is present on IdUser object:

```
INSERT [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([Email], [EmailConfirmed], [PasswordHash], [SecurityStamp], [PhoneNumber], [PhoneNumberConfirmed], [TwoFactorEnabled],[LockoutEndDateUtc], [LockoutEnabled], [AccessFailedCount], [UserName]) 
VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, @2, NULL, @3, @4, NULL, @5, @6, @7)

SELECT [Id] 
FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] 
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Can't you just convert and transfer the existing users to the new tables on the SQL Server level, using T-SQL statements only? Do that once, and then from then on, using the new ASP.NET Identity stuff with all the existing users already present....

Comment: yes, that's my approach currently, it works but it feels a bit clumsy

Answer (score 1):

You have to instruct the Entity Framework that the Id property is not generated by DB and can be set from code.

You can confure it in your mapping, like this:

```
Property(x => x.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Or if you preffer declarative way, add [DatabaseGenerated attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to Id property:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

once you migrate all the data, remove this configuration to restore default Id generation in DB.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but even if i remove the identity field and do identity_insert, i won't be able to set the column back to identity because SQL Server requires that Identity columns are defined all they are created eg they can't be altered into existence?

Comment: That's a good point. I suppose you can create the table in SQL (or using a code-first migration) with Identity option, then set `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` on the EF side (not applying any migrations), use identity_insert, and still retain Identity option on SQL column itself.